# Dynamically added values creating problems during scolling the listview

Tags: android, android-listview

In my android applicattion i have a list view with custom adapter.The adapter has a textview and two buttons(plus & minus button) like in the image below :

[image]

when i click on the plus or minus button the textview value changes...but as soon as i scroll the listview the values are changed of all the textviews.
The code i used is as follows :

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(convertView==null)
    {
        viewHolder=new ViewHolder();//
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.inventory_list_item, null);
        viewHolder.txt_product_name = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_product_name);
        viewHolder.txt_product_units = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_product_units);
        viewHolder.txt_price = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_price);
        viewHolder.txt_qty = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_qty);
        viewHolder.btn_minus = (Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.btn_minus);
        viewHolder.btn_plus= (Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.btn_plus);

        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    }
    else
    {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    viewHolder.btn_minus.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) v.getParent();

            TextView tv = (TextView) ll.getChildAt(1);


            int qty = Integer.parseInt(tv.getText().toString());

            if(qty == 0)
            {

            }
            else
            {
                qty = qty - 1;
                tv.setText(String.valueOf(qty));
            }

        }
    });

    viewHolder.btn_plus.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) v.getParent();

            TextView tv = (TextView) ll.getChildAt(1);

            int qty = Integer.parseInt(tv.getText().toString());


                qty = qty + 1;
                tv.setText(String.valueOf(qty));


        }
    });

    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map = data.get(position);        
    viewHolder.txt_product_name.setText(map.get("ProductName"));
    viewHolder.txt_price.setText(map.get("ProductPrice"));
    viewHolder.txt_product_units.setText(map.get("ProductUnits"));

    return convertView;
}
```

How do i address this issue?

Please help ! thanks in advance !

Comment: you need to add one more filed in your Hashmap and need to set the data from there like how your doing for the product name & price

Comment: @KingofMasses but that value is not predefind...that value comes only if the plus minus button is clicked

Comment: of course it is not predefined, but based on the position (viewholder.btn_plus) you need to add the value into your hashmap and then you need to show it in your listview'

Comment: @KingofMasses could you please give an example ? i am not getting how to implement it the way you are saying! sorry!

Answer (score 0):

Try defining `TextView` tv inside `viewHolder` instead of inside click listener

```
ViewHolder{
TextView tv;
}
```

Do something like you have done for txt_product_name `TextView`

Comment: but i want the value of the textview beside that particular button to change ...that textview is already defined as txt_qty in viewholder

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a model class for that . Create getter setter for each element in your list view Whether is String int or status of open and close .And Pass it to constructor of your adapter class .If you already have a model class then add these parameters to it . And change the property of text change on button click And call notifyDataSetChanged() after it . then you just need if-else in your getView() to change the text .Try it and let me know if you still face some problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have created demo according your scenario ,what i did inside onClick i have updated my data and called notifyDataSetChanged();

whatever you did is very long and heavy process;make it simple .just update your data and called notifyDataSetChanged();if you need sample i can provide you my sample

don't update manually the field of textview .always update the data and get updated data and set to textview

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you can't update the plus(+) and minus(-) values in your listview directly as your tried. Because your not handling any position in your code. So it seams if you change one item count (plus or minus) it will effect on the other items as well (or) else  it will lose the data after scrolling..

So to achieve your task, you need to follow these steps.

- Firstly you need to create a data structure, which holds the positions of your items and count of your items in the list view. Suppose third item in your list view having 5 count (plus values) we can hold both the position and count as well in this data structure.

  So, i am taking a HashMap , where key is String.valueOf(position) and Value is count int. like below

  ```
  HashMap< String,Integers > countDetails= new HashMap< String,Integers >;
  ```

You know the keys since it will be from position "0" to listitem.length. Using the key you can get the count values(probably to hold your item cont details for each and every list item).

**Why Hashmap:** because everytime you change count the new value will be overriden. (Only one unique key is maintained in hashmap).

Usage:: if the user click's the first item minus (-) or plus (+) button you need to hold that count and need to store in the hashmap with the position and count. for example   (position = 0, count = 3) --> - clicked on 1st row--> plus (+) items for 3 times like that.

after clicking plus(+) and (-) values in your list item call the notifyDataChanged() in your list so, that it will update the data in listview.

So, this is the idea how you can achieve your implementation,  here i am giving a sample code for it .

```
class AdapterClass extends ArrayAdapter<String> {


    HashMap<String,Integers> countDetails = new HashMap<String,Integers>;

  // you can use/ declare  all your remaining data product  here 


    public AdapterClass(Context c, String[] items, int imgs[]) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub 
        super(c, R.layout.rowlayout, R.id.quantity, items);
        this.context = c;

    } 

    @Override 
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub 

    if(convertView==null)
     {
        viewHolder=new ViewHolder();//
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.inventory_list_item, null);
        viewHolder.txt_product_name = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_product_name);
        viewHolder.txt_product_units = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_product_units);
        viewHolder.txt_price = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_price);
        viewHolder.txt_qty = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_qty);
        viewHolder.btn_minus = (Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.btn_minus);
        viewHolder.btn_plus= (Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.btn_plus);

        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
     }
     else
     {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
     }



      HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
      map = data.get(position);        
      viewHolder.txt_product_name.setText(map.get("ProductName"));
      viewHolder.txt_price.setText(map.get("ProductPrice"));
      viewHolder.txt_product_units.setText(map.get("ProductUnits"));


        viewHolder.btn_minus.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            int pos=position;

              HashMap<String,Integers> tmpDetails = new HashMap<String,Integers>;

              tmpDetails=countDetails.get(pos);

              int count=tmpDetails.get(pos);  // probably your getting the previous count for the item 


            if(count == 0)
            {

            }

            else
            {
                count = count - 1;
               holder.txt_qty.setText(count.toString());
            }

                countDetails.put(holder.uniqueKey,count); //Key -> String.valueOf(position) and Value -> int count


        }
    });


     viewHolder.btn_plus.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            int pos=position;

              HashMap<String,Integers> tmpDetails = new HashMap<String,Integers>;

              tmpDetails=countDetails.get(pos);

              int count=tmpDetails.get(pos);  // probably your getting the previous count for the item 


            if(count == 0)
            {

            }

            else
            {
                count = count + 1;
               holder.txt_qty.setText(count.toString());
            }

                countDetails.put(holder.uniqueKey,count); //Key -> String.valueOf(position) and Value -> int count


        }
    });

        return row;
    } 



}
```

p.s. I have typed in editor, there might be some compile time error. Also you can store objects of each row against the key so that when you get the count, you can get any other reference too..

Comment: Ok well.. post a new question with all your trails. some body may help you this time !!